# Datepicker function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement showing calender widow when user clicks at the textbox but nothing is happening and I also tried using HTML5 date type control but that also not showing. Please help.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready($(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: you dont have jquery ui call your jquery-ui

Comment: and jQuery ui js and jQuery ui css too then datepicker will show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `jquery-ui` script also Datepicker functionality is defined in `jquery-ui`.

See here: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works but when I try the same thing in my code it doesn't. Idk what might be the issue.

Comment: See error in inspect element.